# Sending Devise emails to custom address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailer, mailing

I'm using Litmus for testing emails, sent by my website, and I'm trying to write a script that will send all the invite/confirm/reset password emails to Litmus-generated addresses, plus to probably couple more email IDs, to test layouts and content.

So I have a CSV file with bunch of addresses I want to send them to. But how do I make Devise send the emails without having a user created? Is it even possible?

Comment: @zERO The tool is called "Devise", not "Device". Please don't change the meaning of posts.

Answer (score 1):

Devise only provides the authentication, what you are trying to do, has nothing to do with authentication, or you have to provide more details or be more explicit about your problem.